# How to set up captcha for wso2 api manager 3.2.0 portals?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

Why WSO2 api manager 3.2.0 portals do not have captcha and How to set up captcha for wso2 api manager 3.2.0 portals like /publisher or /devportal?

Also I want to use it in production environment that no intternet accsess and can not use google captcha.

Comment: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/setting-up-recaptcha/#setting-up-recaptcha

Comment: Thanks, but it's for identity server, I want for publisher and devportal , could you please guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below steps to get the ReCaptcha feature while logging into the APIM-3.2.0 publisher or developer portal.

**Configuring reCaptcha API keys**

1. Go to https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin.
2. In the following UI provide the relevant details.
   [image]
3. Click on "Submit"
4. In the next UI, you will get the site key and the secret key as shown below. Copy those keys.
   [image]

**Configure the APIM 3.2.0 to enable ReCaptcha feature during publisher and devportal logins**

1. Navigate to **{APIM-Home}/repository/conf/deployment.toml** and add the following configurations. Please replace the site key and secret key with the ones you have generated previously.

> ```
> #Enable Google reCAPTCHA
> [recaptcha] 
> enabled= true
>
> #reCaptcha API URL
> api_url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"
>
> #reCaptcha verification URL
> verify_url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify"
>
> #reCaptcha site key
> site_key="<Key>"
>
> #reCaptcha secret key
> secret_key="<Key>"
> ```

2. Re-start the APIM server.
3. Log into the carbon management console.
4. Navigate to Main --> Identity --> Identity Providers --> Resident --> Login Policies --> Captcha for SSO Login
5. You will be able to see the following section.
   [image]
6. Tick the **"Enable captcha always"** and if required you can tick **"Enable captcha after the Max failed attempts"** check box as well.
7. Click on "Update".
8. In WSO2 APIM 3.2.0 publisher and devportal you will be able to see the ReCaptcha feature as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot,  I want to use it in production environment that no intternet accsess and can  I use google captcha?@Saranki Magenthirarajah

Comment: Anytime! You need internet access to use the Google captcha.